# How will I get a counter to display at 1 instead of 0?

Tags: c#

Atm the message to the screen is, enter the weight of turkey number 0

How could I change this to get it to start with the enter the weight of turkey number 1 because if i assign turkeycounter with the value 1 at the beginning am leaving out the weighing of one turkey.  So if the user wanted to enter the weight of 5 turkeys they would only be able to enter the weight fot 4. Im a newb as you can tell!!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TurkeyNumber = 0;
        double TurkeyWeight = 0.00;
        int TurkeyCounter = 0;
        int G1 = 0, G2 = 0, G3 = 0, G4 = 0, G5 = 0, G6 = 0; 



        Console.Write("How many turkeys are you weighing? ");
        TurkeyNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        while (TurkeyCounter < TurkeyNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the weight of turkey number {0}:",TurkeyCounter);
            TurkeyWeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (TurkeyWeight > 12)
            {
                G1 = G1 + 1;       
            }
            if (TurkeyWeight > 10)
            {
                G2 = G2 + 1;
            }
            if (TurkeyWeight > 8)
            {
                G3 = G3 + 1;
            }
            if (TurkeyWeight > 6)
            {
                G4 = G4+ 1;
            }
            if (TurkeyWeight > 4)
            {
                G5 = G5 + 1;
            }
            if (TurkeyWeight <= 12)
            {
                G6 = G6 + 1;
            }





            TurkeyCounter++;             

        }



        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the weight of turkey number {0}:",TurkeyCounter+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is so simple just add `+1` when displaying `TurkeyCounter`.

Another point is do not make seperated if blocks for one item. In according to your logic assume that turkey's weight is `7`. So it adds `+1` `G3`, `G4` and `G6`. So the resulting turkey count would be higher than the user enters.

Besides, I suggest you to use arrays instead of using unique variables. So you can easily manipulate the array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int TurkeyNumber = 0;
    double TurkeyWeight = 0.00;
    int TurkeyCounter = 0;

    int[] G= new int[6];

    Console.Write("How many turkeys are you weighing? ");
    TurkeyNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (TurkeyCounter < TurkeyNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the weight of turkey number {0}:",TurkeyCounter+1);
        TurkeyWeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (TurkeyWeight > 12)
           G[0]++;       
        else if (TurkeyWeight > 10)
           G[1]++;
        else if (TurkeyWeight > 8)
           G[2]++;
        else if (TurkeyWeight > 6)
           G[3]++;
        else if (TurkeyWeight > 4)
           G[4]++;
        else if (TurkeyWeight <= 12) 
           G[5]++;

        TurkeyCounter++;             
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! Cheers for the tip!